# stop until code ran

Tags: vb.net

So im pulling data from a db and then counting all the data on that db but it  counts before the data is pulled. Anyway to stop this?

```
    test.SelectCommand = Ssql
    test.SelectParameters.Clear()
    test.DataBind()

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    counter = OSG.Items.Count

    MsgBox(counter)
```

cheers!

Comment: What is `OSG` in this context?  What is `test`?

Comment: osg datagrid, test is the datasource

Answer (score 3):

Count the data source not the items in the datagrid. The datagrid binding will happen asynchronously and will not be accurate.  For example if your data source is a datatable then you can:

```
Dim x As DataTable = New DataTable
Dim counter As Integer
counter = x.Rows.Count
```

**EDIT:** To count rows in a SQL data source you have to handle the 'selected' event. Make a class level variable called myRowCount, set it in the selected event and use it after the bind statement:

```
Dim myRowCount As Integer
Protected SubSqlDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Selected
     MsgBox(e.AffectedRows())
     myRowCount = e.AffectedRows()
End Sub
```

Then you can use myRowCount elsewhere in the code.

Comment: i get 'Rows' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource'. when i try that?